# Bounding the integral $\int_{-T}^T e^{2 \pi i A t} dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $A$ be any real number and $T$ be any real number greater than $0$.  Does it then follow that $| \int_{-T}^T e^{2 \pi i A t} dt | \leq 1$ for any $A$ and $T$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-T}^{T}e^{2\pi i A t} dt &= \frac{e^{2\pi i AT} - e^{-2\pi i AT}}{2\pi i A} \\
& = \frac{\sin(2\pi A T)}{\pi A} \\
&= 2T \frac{\sin(2\pi A T)}{2\pi A T}\\
\end{aligned}$$
We have
$$\left|\frac{\sin(2\pi A T)}{2\pi A T}\right| \leq 1,$$
and the bound is achieved when $A = 0$, so the best we can say in general is that
$$\left|\int_{-T}^{T}e^{2\pi i A t} dt\right| \leq 2T$$
Note that this coincides with the bound obtained via the triangle inequality:
$$\left|\int_{-T}^{T}e^{2\pi i A t} dt\right| \leq \int_{-T}^{T} |e^{2\pi i A t}| dt = \int_{-T}^{T} 1\ dt = 2T$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Euler's Formula: $e^{2\pi i At}=cos(2\pi At)+isin(2\pi At)$

Splitting the integral up, we see that since sine is an odd function, the integral over it with bounds $[-T,T]$ is equal to $0$.

Integrating the cosine term gives us: $$\frac{sin(2\pi At)}{2\pi A}|_{-T}^T$$ Should be evident from there.